# Create a chart based on hidden secondary table on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

a quick question , I've not been able to find an answer on the internet. I've 3 report tables on 1 Dataset , 2 of these reports are hidden and the only reason they exist is to display data on a chart.

The problem is that I can't create the chart using either one of these hidden tablix reports  as a source , the chart is pulling the data from the first tablix report added to the Dataset which is not hidden.

[I need to create a chart for each of the highlithed tablix report tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssMEJ.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to here?  SSRS charts pull data from the datasets, not the tables in the report...

Comment: I thought there was a way for the chart to pull data from the tables instead of using the Dataset but I've never tried to use other Datasets to display data on charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not possible** in SSRS that a tablix is your datasource for a chart. The datasource of your chart can only be a dataset. Also a tablix datasource can only be a dataset. Under **Chart properties > Dataset name** you will find only datasets in the drop down. You have to edit your query the way you need it for your chart.

You have this option in Power BI. There you can import your dataset in a table, edit this table as often as you want and use the end table as your chart datasource.